# Add "\n" to certain elements of a string vector based on a condition

Tags: r, regex, string, function, character

Say we have a string vector named `vec`. Is there a way to add `"\n"` before the **first whole word (i.e., terms of at least two characters)** of the elements of `vec` that exceed 10 characters?

My `desired_vec` is shown below.

*(This is a representative toy example, but I highly appreciate for the answer to be a function.)*

```
vec = c("Van Beuningen et al b", "bbbb & zz", "AA, BB, & CC")

desired_vec = c("Van Beuningen \net al b", "bbbb & zz", "AA, BB, & \nCC")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try a regular expression replace like this

```
gsub("^(.{9}.*?) (?=\\w{2,})(.*)", "\\1 \n\\2",vec, perl = TRUE)
# [1] "Van Beuningen \net al b" "bbbb & zz"              
# [3] "AA, BB, & \nCC"
```

That will make sure you have some letters at the start, then find the first space followed by at least 2 character and then will insert a new line

Comment: Thank you. Part of my intention was also to add `"\n"` before any element that exceeds the 10nth character. For instance, if an element was `"Rummel & Bitchener"` your current method doesn't add a `"\n"` before `"Bitchener"` which itself exceeds the 10-character limit. Can such a condition be possibly added to your current solution?

Comment: I don’t understand what you are asking. Your third example doesn’t have any words over 10 letters but your desired output has a new line.

Comment: 10 characters includes the blank spaces.